# Is it possible to 'disable' other apps with an app of my own?

Tags: ios

I was wondering if its possible to write an ios app that 'disables' other apps from opening?

For example, when I press the disable button on my app, I cannot open whatsapp for the next 15 minutes.

If that's not possible, could a workaround such as blocking all HTTP requests to a certain URL be possible? or even blocking (or turning off) notifications from certain apps?

I've also been wondering whether or not a security module might disallow such code..

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the suggestion you made in your question will work on a AppStore app. Since the app is sandboxed it can not interact on the level you want with the system.

Your only possibility is to write an app for jailbroken devices.

Comment: Gah, dissapointing! What about about adding apps to the 'do not include' section in the Notification Center? Is an app able to modify or change settings on the system?

Comment: No, no app is able to do this. Not even for it's self. This settings are totally controlled by the user.

Comment: Alright then, thank you very much for the help - saved me a lot of time.

Comment: On a side-note: I believe this is possible on an Android phone!

Comment: Yes, Android is a more open platform, you will be able to much more there. This openness is also allows for easy of privacy breaches.

Answer (score 1):

There might be private API present as per your need but one thing is clear if you target for Apple AppStore ,it will be rejected due to its policy as aslo said by other person. Moreover ,If you still wana develop it you should go for it and there is [Cydia](https://cydia.saurik.com/) which is a appstore for jail broken phone so you could upload your app and try to sell it off. Hope this info is useful for you.

Comment: @oOTesterOo your welcome buddy.. you could also tick me as your answer :)